# PHP sqlsrv_connect Error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL Server with PHP and failing. I'm running PHP7.2 and I've installed Microsoft Drivers 5.2 for PHP for SQL Server and Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

**Here is the code I'm using...**

```
$serverName = "severname\MSSQLSERVER";

$conn_array = array (
    "UID" => "username",
    "PWD" => "password",
    "Database" => "databasename",
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $conn_array);
if ($conn){
    echo "connected";
}else{
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

**and here is the error message I'm getting...**

```
> Array ( 
>         [0] => Array ( 
>             [0] => 08001 
>             [SQLSTATE] => 08001 
>             [1] => 87 
>             [code] => 87 
>             [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].    
>             [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. 
>         ) [1] => Array ( 
>             [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 
>             [1] => 0 [code] => 0 
>             [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired 
>             [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired 
>         ) [2] => Array ( 
>             [0] => 08001 
>             [SQLSTATE] => 08001 
>             [1] => 87 [code] => 87 
>             [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
> accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
> configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
> Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
> accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
> configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
> Server Books Online.
>         )
>     )
```

**Update:** After removing the instance name I get this error... SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'USERNAME'.

Comment: Your instance name / aka schema is named `MSSQLSERVER`? Not clear what you've maybe obfuscated or what might just be plain wrong.

Comment: Thanks for offering some assistance. After removing the instance name I get this error... SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'USERNAME'.

Comment: Please update your question for the new errors you've encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ficuscr hints at, most likely your problem is the instance name.  `MSSQLSERVER` is the instance name of the *default* instance which you do not refer to using the `server\instance` format.  You just use `server`.  You only have to use `server\instance` format for named instances.

Assuming this is the case, your first line should be

```
$serverName = "severname";
```

Comment: When I remove the instance name and use just the server name, I get the following error...

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user USERNAME'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'USERNAME'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'USERNAME'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'USERNAME'. ) )

Comment: That's actually good!  If you're getting that error then you've at least made a successful network connection to SQL server which is farther than you were.  Now you just need to fix the username and password that you're passing.

Comment: "PASSWORD"? That's amazing! I've got the same combination on my luggage!

Comment: @ficuscr Classic.  Might just go pop that in the dvd player.

Comment: Thanks again for your help guys. I didn't setup the username and password. The IT department did that for me. Before I ask them to double check it, is there any chance this error could be cause by something else?

Comment: I think you are good @JohnDoesoph. `Login failed for user 'USERNAME'.` is as @squillman stated pretty indicative you are reaching the server and simply failing authentication because of those bogus credentials.

Comment: @JohnDoesoph If you are using Windows authentication to connect to SQL Server you may find this helpful. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-windows-authentication?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @squillman No, I'm trying to connect using SQL Server Authentication. I'm still waiting for IT to double check the username and password. As soon as I'm able to connect I'll mark the answer correct.